# How to specify a driver for a char device?

Tags: drivers, usb, udev, fuse, v4l

I'm trying to make a usb camera to work on raspberry pi, the problem is every time I plug it, it automatically create a char file under `/dev/video0` that points to `cuse` as it's driver:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/dev/char $ ls -lh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jul  7 16:06 241:0 -> ../../devices/virtual/cuse/video0
```

cuse doesn't make the camera work properly, I need it to bind to the `video4linux` driver, I have installed `v4l-utils` already, but it won't takeover automatically.

How can I manually switch it to `video4linux` driver? Thanks